How to run a program with su privilege without using sudo?
I have this in my .bashrc file
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin

I can run a program anywhere inside the directory set:
adb devices // but no device showing

Because there is some privilege issue, the adb command needs sudo to show results:
sudo adb devices // command not found

I got command not found. However, I can run the command by changing the directory to where adb resides in and get the correct results.
My questions are:

How can I enable sudo to find adb in cmdline-tools/latest/bin without changing dir
How can I enable the command adb devices to run without sudo and still get results.


hmm, what's the difference between sudo which adb, and which adb? I have a rough theory on what's wrong - that sudo runs as root and its not in root's path. 2) may not be possible. Personally I'd just use the full path

T D Nguyen: The correct file to place your export commands is in the~/.profile file. Placing export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin in ~/.bashrc can cause $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin to be appended to the PATH more than once.


How can I enable sudo to find adb in cmdline-tools/latest/bin without changing dir

Can you just run sudo cmdline-tools/latest/bin/adb ?

(Assuming cmdline-tools is a sub-dictorectory.  If it is the top-level folder in the root directory, use "sudo /cmdline-tools/latest/bin/adb".)


How to run a program with su privilege without using sudo
How can I enable the command adb devices to run without sudo and still get results.

That would be with setuid and having the owner of the file be root.
chown root.root  <file>
chmod 4755  <file>


Setuid is a permission set in Unix-like operating systems that allows a user to execute a program with the permissions of the file's owner, instead of the user who executed it;  Setuid is short for "set user identity"

There are security implications to using setuid especially with root being the owner, so recognize that and if it matters for what you are doing.

I assume in this case <file> would be $ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/adb.

By default, sudo discards the $PATH environmental variable for security reasons.
Based on this answer, you can add the following to your bashrc file and restart shell:
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'


I believe user ron has an answer, which may solve your problem. You can try my answer, if for some reason ron's answer does not work. The difference between the answers is ron's answer changes the euid to 0 for adb, while my answer changes the uid to 0 for adb.

The examples given in this answer assume each of the following variables have the value shown. When using this answer, make the appropriate substitutions.
HOME=/home/dma
USER=dma

One way to accomplish what you have described in your question would be to create the following two files.
File to Eliminate Need for Password
This file can be created by using the following command.
sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/${USER}_sudoers <<< "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: $HOME/Android/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/adb"

An alternative method to create this file would be to use a text editor. For example, you could enter the command below.
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/$USER_sudoers

Below is an example of what to enter into the editor.
dma ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: $/home/dma/Android/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/adb

File to Eliminate Need to Enter sudo and the Path.
This file can be created by using the following commands.
sudo tee /usr/local/bin/adb <<< '#!/bin/bash'
sudo tee -a /usr/local/bin/adb <<< 'sudo $HOME'/Android/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/adb "$@"'
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/adb


An alternative method to create this file would be to use a text editor. For example, you could enter the command below.
sudo nano /usr/local/bin/adb

Below is an example of what to enter into the editor.
#!/bin/bash
sudo /home/dma/Android/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/adb "$@"

When finished using the editor to create this file, enter the command given below.
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/adb

